# Play Google (Android store) Statistics

Tags: android

I'm guessing that these stats I can see in my Developer Console are not in realtime. Does anybody know what time they update them at?

My statistics are low, at the moment its only showing 11th of march to the 12th. Does this mean that I haven't had any downloads on the 13th or 14th or that it has not updated yet?

13th and 14th are not visible on the graph at all the line stops at the 12th. Does this mean it just hasn't updated yet?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs [android.stackexchange.com](http://android.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Paresh: This question is most emphatically _off-topic_ at [android.se].

Comment: @AlE. I thought it could be belonged to AE because it's not related to android programming but regarding Google play (android store) so.

Comment: @Paresh: That doesn't automatically make it on-topic for the other site. From [the Help Center](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): "Please note the following topics are expressly off-topic here: ... Issues with the Google Play Store (or any other app marketplace) from the point of view of a developer or publisher"

Comment: @AlE. Thanks for the link and point. I am really apologized for my closing vote.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> > " Does anybody know what time they update them at? "

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139628&topic=16285&ctx=topic

"
These statistics are refreshed on a daily basis. In some cases, we group together similar values of the metrics, such as minor versions of the Android.
"

> > "Does this mean it just hasn't updated yet?"

My guess would be yes.

You may also enjoy this video from Google Dev Advocate Reto Meier aka RadioactiveYak's Youtube channel - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dr5sGLY210Q

Comment: My own recent experience a year later than this question was posted is that stats actually update on my Developer Dashboard a little before 6:00am PST, and that the updated stats reflect what was true at midnight of that day (i.e., about six hours earlier).  So I can imagine some process that takes a snapshot of stats starting at midnight and then posts them about six hours later.  I guess the snapshot might actually be taken any time between midnight and 6:00am.

Answer (score 8):

No. of downloads are generally updated after 2 days.
But ratings and reviews are updated at real time.

Comment: This fits to my observation. It seems to lag 2 days behind. Kinda annoying, but good to know it happened to others as well. "daily updated statistics" my ass...

Answer (score 5):

> These statistics are refreshed on a daily basis at 12:00 am PST.

From here: http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139628

Answer (score 3):

It's not daily - my stats currently are a little over 2 days out of date.

I think it's random.. it'll update before the end of the month (for accounting) but can't be relied upon.

Comment: Yeah, my app has 9 rating has 3 days and still show 1-5 downloads